# How do we call $g(n)$ if $f(n)\sim g(n)$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Assume $f(n)$ is a complicated function and we are interested in its asymptotic behavior. Assume $g(n)$ is a relatively simple function and we have $f(n)\sim g(n)$, where $f(n)\sim g(n)$ means $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=1$ (assume $f(n), g(n)>0$.)

If $g(n)=a$ is a constant, we can call it is the limit of $f(n)$. I am wondering how do we call $g(n)$ if it is just some function? I thought we can call that $g(n)$ is asymptote of $f(n)$. But it seems "asymptote" is not for this situation?

Comment: I think saying that $g(n)$ is *an* asymptote of $f(n)$ is fine.  (Not *the* asymptote.)  Depending on how $g(n)$ is chosen, one might also say that it's the leading order behavior of $f(n)$.

Comment: The terminology is $f$ is asymptotic to $g$. Note that this goes both ways and "relatively simple" is not necessary. Note also that $g$ is not unique. i.e. $\sqrt{x^2+1}\sim x$ but also $\sqrt{x^2+1}\sim x+ \frac{1}{2x}$. The former is a first order asymptotic approximation, the latter a second order.

Comment: @tomasliam: Note that you are using $\sim$ to denote an asymptotic expansion, which is not the same as OP's definition.  Under OP's definition, $\sqrt{x^2+1}\sim x + \frac{1}{7x}$ or $x + \log x$ is just as true as $x + \frac{1}{2x}$.

Comment: Yes I know. But what I said still holds